# What is the minimum height of a binary tree with $n$ vertices?

Tags: graph-theory

What is the minimum height of a binary tree with $n$ vertices?

Is it $$\lceil \log_2n\rceil$$,

$$\lfloor \log_2{n} \rfloor$$

or

$$\lceil \log_2{n+1} \rceil -1$$

Comment: what's your definition of vertices in this context?

Comment: @EhsanM.Kermani Or should it be $\lceil \log_2{n+1} \rceil -1$

Comment: @Julia, let me be more clear. For 1 vertex, it's 0, for 2 and 3 vertices it's 1, for 4, 5, 6,7 it's 2, so it should be the floor of $\log_2 n$ not the ceiling!

Comment: @EhsanM.Kermani Thanks. I thought my initial result was a bit dodgy. I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: A full binary tree]

So we can see that if we let $n$ and $x$ be a natural number then,

Height 0 - $2^0$

Height 1 - **$2$ $\le$ n $\le $$3$**

*Height 2* - **$4$ $\le$ n $\le $$7$**

*Height 3* - **$8$ $\le$ n $\le $$15$**

*Height 4* - **$16$ $\le$ n $\le $$31$**

Using mathematical deduction we can conclude,

*Height* **x** - **$2^x$ $\le$ n $\le $$2^{x+1}-1$**

And since we want the least number of terms for the minimum height of the graph we take into consideration the term on the left of the inequality. Further, in order to get the term of the least number of vertices of a given height n must equal to $2^x$ and so,

$n=$ $2^x$ $\Longrightarrow$ $\log_2{n}$ $=x$

Therefore in order to get the least number in each interval we can conclude,

$\lfloor \log_2{n} \rfloor$ $=$ $x$

Comment: Let me just add for completeness that $\lfloor \log_2{n} \rfloor = \lceil \log_2{(n+1)} \rceil -1$

Answer (score -1):

I think there is a mistake in your idea, which is about the range of $n$.

For example, with height $2$,  $3 \leq n$, not $4$, and of height $3$, it is $4 \leq n$.